# Remove last n lines from file using nodejs

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm trying to remove the last 3 lines from a file using fs as part of nodejs. I'm currently reading the file into memory and then writing it again without the 3 lines, but I'm sure there is a more efficient way that doesn't involve reading the whole file into memory.

My code now

```
fs.readFile(filename, function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    theFile = data.toString().split("\n");
    theFile.splice(-3, 3);
    fs.writeFile(filename, theFile.join("\n"), function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("Removed last 3 lines");
        console.log(theFile.length);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's create a huge file:

```
$ base64 /dev/urandom | head -1000000 > /tmp/crap
$ wc -l /tmp/crap
1000000 /tmp/crap
$ du -sh /tmp/crap
74M /tmp/crap
```

Here is your code:

```
$ cat /tmp/a.js
var fs = require('fs');

var filename = '/tmp/crap1';

fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
    if(err) throw err;
    theFile = data.toString().split("\n");
    theFile.splice(-3,3);
    fs.writeFile(filename, theFile.join("\n"), function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("Removed last 3 lines");
    console.log(theFile.length);
    });
});
```

And here is mine:

```
$ cat /tmp/b.js
var fs = require('fs'),
    util = require('util'),
    cp = require('child_process');

var filename = '/tmp/crap2';
var lines2nuke = 3;
var command = util.format('tail -n %d %s', lines2nuke, filename);

cp.exec(command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    var to_vanquish = stdout.length;
    fs.stat(filename, (err, stats) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        fs.truncate(filename, stats.size - to_vanquish, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('File truncated!');
        })
    });
});
```

Let's make copies of the same file:

```
$ cp /tmp/crap /tmp/crap1
$ cp /tmp/crap /tmp/crap2
```

Let's see who is faster:

```
$ time node a.js
Removed last 3 lines
999998
node a.js  0.53s user 0.19s system 99% cpu 0.720 total

$ time node b.js
File truncated!
node b.js  0.08s user 0.01s system 100% cpu 0.091 total
```

When I increased the filesize 10 times, my system ran out of memory with a.js; but with b.js, it took:

```
$ time node b.js
File truncated!
node b.js  0.07s user 0.03s system 6% cpu 1.542 total
```

My code uses [`tail`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html), which doesn't read the whole file, it seeks to the end then read blocks backwards until the expected number of lines have been reached, then it displays the lines in the proper direction until the end of the file. Now I now the number of bytes to disappear. Then I use [`fs.stat`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback), which tells me the total number of bytes in the file. Now, I know how many bytes I actually want in the file at the end, after removal of those last `n` lines. At the end, I use [`fs.truncate`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_truncate_path_len_callback), which causes the regular file to be truncated to a size of precisely the size (in bytes) specified to it.

Update:

OP says that the platform is Windows. In that case, we can modify this program to *not* invoke another utility, but do everything in node itself. Fortunately, the required functionality has already been made available for us as the node module [`read-last-lines`](https://github.com/alexbbt/read-last-lines). Now the updated, os-agnostic code looks like:

```
$ npm install read-last-lines
$ cat /tmp/c.js 
var fs = require('fs'),
    rll = require('read-last-lines');

var filename = '/tmp/crap2';
var lines2nuke = 3;

rll.read(filename, lines2nuke).then((lines) => {
    var to_vanquish = lines.length;
    fs.stat(filename, (err, stats) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        fs.truncate(filename, stats.size - to_vanquish, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('File truncated!');
        })
    });
});
```

And on the 10x size file, it took:

```
$ time node c.js
File truncated!
node c.js  0.14s user 0.04s system 8% cpu 2.022 total
```

Comment: Please sir, I'm getting **'tail' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**. Could you help me? Running Node on Win10. Thank you.

Comment: @statosdotcom I've updated the answer such that it should work on Windows too.

Comment: Nehal J Wani, thank you very much. Worked like a charm. Sorry to waste your time. +1. God Bless.

Comment: FYI it's always good practice to propose multi platform solutions from the beginning... I also use Linux as my main platform but I know that not all people does, so I always think about solutions which will work everywhere.