# How to remove last line in the text(.txt) file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have:

```
let removeString = (fileName, strToRemove) => {
    fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', function(err, data){
    let toRemove = data.replace(strToRemove+'\n','')
    fs.writeFile(fileName, toRemove)
    })
};
```

This successfully removes non first or last line, but how do I remove from

```
first
second
third
```

`First` or `third` using fs?

Comment: I have tried your code and it did remove 'first' when calling removeString('file.txt', 'first').

Comment: Suspiciously [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248060/removing-a-line-from-a-txt-file), but a different account ..?

Comment: @Teemu and that one again looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50237509/1427878 ...

Comment: @CBroe Indeed, all the questions were including a "[tag]" in the title too ...

Comment: ... I saw [tag] in other questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` to split the file into an array of lines then remove whichever line you want, then rejoin the array into a string using `join` then write the file.

Example:

```
let removeString = (fileName, strToRemove) => {
    fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', function(err, data){
        let splitArray = data.split('\n');
        splitArray.splice(splitArray.indexOf(strToRemove), 1);
        let result = splitArray.join('\n');
        fs.writeFile(fileName, result)
    })
};
```

Comment: ReferenceError: indexOf is not defined

Comment: Fixed it. Replace it with `splitArray.indexOf`.

Comment: And you made a mistake, data.split('\n\); 
May be data.split('\n'); :)

Comment: Sorry about that. Glad I was able to help though :)

Comment: This DOES answer the question, and there's no mention of the file being massively large or anything, so for the quick ones it deserves a +1.

Answer (score 3):

The above solution is not optimized for a very large file as it reads the whole file. If you are on non-windows platform, you can run unix [tail](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) command. If on windows, you can look at [read-last-lines](https://github.com/alexbbt/read-last-lines).

Look at this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466149/remove-last-n-lines-from-file-using-nodejs)